# how can i view the elasticsearch data in indeax, how can i create the schema to kafka topic twitter data

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka

root@devserver:~/c-kafka# curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_search?pretty'
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get help here you need to be much clearer in what you're trying to do, what you've tried so far, and so on. There is some good guidance here: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: Also try to ask 1 question at a time, and put some context on your question, right now it is only code...